# Generating correct url with Url.Action when Id is dynamic (client side)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

From JQGrid , on Double Click I am trying to navigate the user to a new page  as per the following code

```
ondblClickRow : function (id) {
                location.href = '<% = Url.Action("Index","MyFeature") %>/' + id;
            }
```

The code errors our as

the  resulting url is

http://localhost:8080/MyFeature.mvc/9a1347dc-60b0-4b3b-9570-9ed100b6bc6a

Adding Index after controller does the trick but is there a better way to do this

```
location.href = '<% = Url.Action("Index","MyFeature") %>/Index/' + id;
```

http://localhost:8080/MyFeature.mvc/Index/9a1347dc-60b0-4b3b-9570-9ed100b6bc6a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some placeholder that you will replace on the client:

```
ondblClickRow : function (id) {
    var url = '<%= Url.Action("Index", "MyFeature", new { id = "__id__" }) %>';
    window.location.href = url.replace('__id__', id);
}
```

Comment: Wow let me try this , I am sure it should work and gave me some more ideas. Thanks. I will update the answer as soon as I  have done testing

Comment: @ Darin - it did work. I also tried something which may not be lead to issues later (not sure).   ...... '<%= Url.Action("Index", "MyFeature", new { id = "/" }) %>' + id;. This also worked.